# Recaptcha not working in user register form

Tags: 7, ajax, forms, captcha

I am using google recaptcha in drupal 7 for user registration. The captcha works fine in the normal user register page but doesn't appear in the pop up dialog box for user registration?

some more info:

- i created the pop register form using ajax
- i checked the css of the site and the `<div>` of the captcha is present but doesn't have any content inside it like when it does when it is working.

Comment: `i created the pop register form using ajax`  ←  that's probably your problem

Comment: are you suggesting that Ajax doesn't support the Recaptcha? some insight will be great please.

Comment: I think it's likely that your Ajax is not loading the captcha's div and/or the captcha's js file.

Comment: ok thanks , i will look into it and let you know here. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some browsing, i found the Patch for the Recaptcha module that enables it to be used in ajax register form.

Please find the link to the node  [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1463768)

Cheers.